# How can I use one computer but two different desktop outputs?

Tags: linux, video, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, display

Is it possible to use one PC, and output two different desktopd with different activity? Such as below:

```
     One PC
       |
 -------------
 ^           ^
DVI          HDMI
^              ^
\               \
 Desktop 1      Desktop 2
  |                |
  Youtube          > Presentation -> LCD Screen 2
  |                > No audio, display only
  > LCD Screen 1
  > Video/Audio
```

Comment: Extended desktop does't work for you because…?

Comment: Do you want to be able to move windows between them - or do you want seperate X sessions?

Comment: I can not share Desktop 1 with Desktop 2. Because Desktop 2 is a touch screen. and Desktop 1 is advertising screen/sliders/display.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Display 1 will have resolution of 1080i (no inputs), and Desktop 2 will have 1024x768 with touch screen to take commands.

Comment: You wouldn't share. [Read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor#Span_or_extended_desktop_mode). Second paragraph. [See example arrangement here](http://blog.dabitaguilera.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/virtual-desktop.png). This is how you connect a large screen to a laptop computer and stay sane.

Comment: @DanielBeck: i have second problem by doing extended desktop. How can i rotate only the Desktop 1 but not Desktop 2? -90degree.

Comment: I don't have a Linux desktop system, but I'd suggest you get a proper graphics driver and use one of the many tutorials you find online when searching for "rotate linux screen". It's always screen specific, AFAICT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup where I through the nvidia driver have two screens defined through TwinView in the X window manager. One for console access and one for TV output. By manipulating the DISPLAY variable I can decide on which screen programs should do their output to.

In your case you would set the DISPLAY variable to ':0.1' (if LCD Screen 1 is the default display) before running the presentation software.